# SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 115-116: malformed \N character escape

Tags: python, cmd

I got the following error:

```
C:\Users\DELL>C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe   D:\Arduino\ckAnimation_generator.py
  File "D:\Arduino\ckAnimation_generator.py", line 19
    bloodySettingsPath ="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\KeyDominator2\\KeyDominator2\\UserLog\\Keyboard\\B857Rcir_2178872A\\English\\Setting\\SLED\NumberPadAtRight\\Setting.ini"
                       ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 115-116: malformed \N character escape
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What is your question? Where is your code? Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This should be tagged python, not cmd.

Answer (score 0):

Either escape the REVERSE SOLIDUS (backslash) characters or specify the string as raw.

```
bloodySettingsPath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\KeyDominator2\\KeyDominator2\\UserLog\\Keyboard\\B857Rcir_2178872A\\English\\Setting\\SLED\\NumberPadAtRight\\Setting.ini"
```

or

```
bloodySettingsPath = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\KeyDominator2\KeyDominator2\UserLog\Keyboard\B857Rcir_2178872A\English\Setting\SLED\NumberPadAtRight\Setting.ini"
```